# type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected. } expected

Tags: c#

I've tried to find a solution but found none.

The problem seems to be the public int number but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrimTal
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { // } expected

            public int number; 
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Ditt nummer är: " + number);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
} // type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Comment: You cannot use  `public` inside method. `int number;` is enough or move `public int number;` where class starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties must be "outside", like this:

```
class Program
{
    // Properties
    public static int Number {get; set;}

    // Methods
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 

        Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ditt nummer är: " + Number);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Or you can use a local variable: `int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` in `Main`.

Comment: Make your property `static`

Comment: @X-TECH you're right X-TECH. I edited it. Thanks for comment.